# WCF client for JAX-WS MTOM with streaming service

Tags: wcf, jax-ws

We have JAX-WS web service like this:

```
public class NamedDataHandlerContainer {
    public String options; // format is option1_name=option1_value;option2_name=option2_value
    @XmlMimeType("application/octet-stream") public DataHandler dataHandler;
}

@WebService
public interface mtomserver {
    @WebMethod public int saveFile(String name,
    @XmlMimeType("application/octet-stream") List<NamedDataHandlerContainer> contents,
    @XmlMimeType("application/octet-stream") @WebParam(mode = WebParam.Mode.OUT) Holder<List<NamedDataHandlerContainer>> results);
}
```

When WSDL for that web service is processed with SvcUtil of .NET 4.0, it generates byte[] type for NamedDataHandlerContainer.dataHandler:

```
public partial class namedDataHandlerContainer;
{
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, Order = 0)]
    public string options;

    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form = System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified, DataType = "base64Binary", Order = 1)]
    public byte[] dataHandler;
}
```

However, in App.config it generates Mtom artifacts:

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="mtomserverImplPortBinding" messageEncoding="Mtom" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000000" />
</basicHttpBinding>
```

(maxReceivedMessageSize is added by us to allow large attacghments). In fact WCF client sends MTOM attachment to the service - we are dumping HTTP payloads and confirm that:

```
--uuid:394d798b-e43e-47cc-82dd-64e32ef51edd+id=1
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/0>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
Content-Type: application/xop+xml;charset=utf-8;type="text/xml"

<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><saveFile xmlns="http://wsserver.mtomtest/"><arg0 xmlns="">myfile.bin</arg0><arg1 xmlns=""><options>my options from .NET</options><dataHandler><xop:Include href="cid:http://tempuri.org/1/634993057692269386" xmlns:xop="http://www.w3.org/2004/08/xop/include"/></dataHandler></arg1></saveFile></s:Body></s:Envelope>
--uuid:394d798b-e43e-47cc-82dd-64e32ef51edd+id=1
Content-ID: <http://tempuri.org/1/634993057692269386>
Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

<binary content goes here>
```

JAX-WS can successfully apply streaming to such payload. However, is there a way to implement streaming on .NET side? I have read MSDN where it is explicitly said that only one parameter with streaming enabled may exist. However, is there a way to have custom message serializer (or something custom, I'm not an expert in WCF) and still avoid loading entire payload into memory.

Answer (score 0):

WCF has a configuration to enable streaming.  You don't need to write any additional code to achieve this.

```
<basicHttpBinding>
    <binding name="mtomserverImplPortBinding" messageEncoding="Mtom" maxReceivedMessageSize="1000000000" transferMode="Streamed"/>
</basicHttpBinding>
```

Source: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms789010.aspx